Can a district attorney dismiss their own traffic ticket?
Recently in the local news, I watched the body camera footage of the Monroe County NY District Attorney getting a traffic ticket.  During the video she exclaims to go ahead and write the ticket because she is the one that prosecutes it (I presumed she was implying she would make it go away).
Can DA's handle their own traffic violations?

It could be that someone else in the office will dismiss it or do something to make it go away. It isn't as if the DA is the only one who can do that.

Maybe, but she clearly says at the end "I will be prosecuting myself".

Just because she said that to the officer writing her the ticket doesn't mean that she would actually be the person doing the prosecuting.  There are lots of rules around conflict of interest when it comes to who can lead a prosecution and if the person being prosecuted is the same as the one who is leading it that is a clear conflict of interest. In cases like this the case will always go to someone else.

Aren't they getting a bit above themself? A tin god? Even the president's supposed immunity is subject to debate.

Yes, @WeatherVane, they are.  Even if the claim were flatly true, it's a bad look.  Which I guess is why the video is getting attention.

@JoeW The question of whether she could and whether she would are separate issues, and the question is about the former. It might be made more specific by asking whether there are any specific provisions against a DA dismissing, either directly or indirectly, a case against her (it seems reasonable that someone could do that, insofar as we cannot reasonably assume that any case whatsoever brought against a DA is justifiable. My guess is that maybe a (panel of) judge(s) or the state AG could do it.)

@sdenham There are generally laws/rules that prevent someone from prosecuting it themselves. The statement that was made could have been an empty statement in order to prevent the ticket from being written in the first place rather then what would actually happen. It could have also been to indicate that someone else would drop the ticket. It isn't that uncommon for law enforcement officials and those connected to them to get out of tickets because of those connections.

@JoeW Indeed, it is quite possible that the DA's intent was any of those things, individually or in some conjunction, but the question is not about the DA's intent (which would not be a valid question here, anyway.)

No, in the case of a conflict of interest, a special prosecutor would be appointed to handle the matter. Most likely, this would be the DA of an adjoining county.
In New York, this special district attorney is appointed by the superior criminal court (NY Cty L § 701).
This frequently happens in a more mundane situation: when a new DA is elected. As they have almost always practiced law beforehand, they run into cases and clients they have defended in the past.

It is, however, not surprising that the DAs from adjoining counties often know each other professionally. The willingness of each DA to prosecute their colleagues would be pertinent to this question.

This answers whether it would be lawful for the DA to handle the matter themselves, but it would be useful to add to this what kind of oversight or procedural safeguards would compel them to declare the conflict of interest and initiate this process. After all, the inherent problem with sustaining conflicts of interest is the motivation it creates to make improper decisions, and the first form this impropriety could take is allowing the conflict to persist undisclosed.

Are DA's even involved with traffic tickets in the first place? The only time I ever fought a ticket (it was for speeding), I went to a magistrate's office. Just me, him, and the cop. Not in court, no lawyers involved.

@Barmar The DA is responsible (city attorney when you get a ticket under ordinance). A police officer's authority to prosecute minor infractions themselves is delegated from the DA. In NY, see People v. Soddano 86 N.Y.2d 727 (1995).

So while this is normally delegated to the officer, a DA could prosecute it himself if they wanted (but not in the case where the offender is themselves, due to COI)?
